# Why did I get a notification for an edit on another user's post?

Tags: support, notifications, users

[This edit](https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/108074) was on a question that was not asked by me, but by another user with the same username as me (Nils).

The notification was in my Stack Exchange inbox. I think this is a bug somewhere in the notification system. Notifications should probably be based on UIDs rather than on matching names, since names have duplicates.

Comment: But ... you are [Nils](https://superuser.com/users/91019/nils) ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seeing your [communities profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/492646/nils?tab=accounts), the [Super User account](https://superuser.com/users/91019/nils) is yours. The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/311851) you have posted 7 years before was edit by another user. So you are receiving the notification.

So it is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and it is working as expected.

Comment: I am getting old. :-( So the question is propably why my Avatar is missing there (and here). But that's a different Q.